# Magento tax_class_id not importing

Tags: magento-1.9, import, tax-class

I want to import bulk products using csv template in Magento.

I am unable to import a column **tax_class_id**.

I have given the value as eg: MA001234.

The datatype used in backend is 'int'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, tax_class_id is magento default attribute and the values should be predefined.

If you need new value in dropdown, please add new value in `Sales => Tax => Product Tax Classes.`

You cant import "MA001234" all of the sudden. Hope this make sense.

Comment: yes I added the value in Product Tax Classes, But i want the default name to be named as "tax_class". If i do so, i get attribute "tax_class_id" not found.